# Problem Building camera_calibration_parsers - where is yaml-cpp/yaml.h?

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Updated my version of ROS - and I'm getting a build error in camera_calibration_parsers.

Anyone any idea where yaml.h is? as in the error message:

```
~/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse_yml.cpp:3:27: fatal error: yaml-cpp/yaml.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Most other packages are building without issue

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50650/problem-building-camera_calibration_parsers---where-is-yaml-cpp/yaml.h?/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No matter found it...

https://github.com/andmej/proxydo

and

http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1